# PHP API returns an array - need to reuse it in variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a PHP script that dumps data from an API.

The dump is an array

```
 print_r($answer);
```

outputs

```
 Array ( [success] => 1 [serial] => s001 [url] => http://gooole.com )
```

I want to have another variable called $url that holds the value url from the array (held in $answer) in PHP.

I'm unfamiliar with this.

Comment: `$url = $answer['url']`?

Comment: `$url = $answer["url"];` ?

Comment: Learn basic PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [extract()](http://php.net/extract) it will take the keys from an array, and create variable of the same name to store them in. There are a few flags you can pass it, to determine exactly what it does with things like pre-existing variables of the same name.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments on your question, though, `$url = $answer['url'];` is probably the simplest way to go.